# Books dealing with the g3 Queen's Indian

Tags: opening, books, queens-indian

What are the best repertoire or opening books, if any, advocating the g3 variation vs the Queen's Indian for White, in terms of analysis and verbal explanations of the main plans / ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will have to explore through some of the new (and older) literature on the Queen's Indian to give you better recommendations, but off the top of my head I recall at least 3:

- [Play the Queen's Indian by Andrew Greet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857445805): if I remember correctly the fianchetto variations are discussed somewhere at the end of his book. One plus about this book is that it's quite readable.
- [Starting Out: The Queen's Indian by John Emms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857443632): This is probably what you're looking for, there's an extensive study on the `g3` variation (up to 70 pages almost). Also see his post [here](http://www.chesspublishing.com/content/10/apr12.htm).
- [Queen's Indian Defence by Jacob Aagaard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857443004): I've heard good things about this one, but haven't read it myself, see chapter two. Apparently it contains numerous references to insightful games, for whatever variation that is covered in the book.

Finally, to browse through the known variations and played games, there are many websites that you can look through, but these two should get you started:

- [365chess](http://www.365chess.com/eco/E15_Queen's_Indian_4.g3)
- Queen's Indian (E15) page on [chessgames](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessopening?eco=e15)

Comment: How about some sort of repertoire book with this line? Do you have The Kaufman Repertoire for Black and White?

Comment: I have the starting out Queen's Indian book. It goes over a bunch of different lines, with explanations of the ideas behind each line and illustrative games. For each line it also tells you if you need to know the theory or if you can get by using opening principles. Based on that information, you can just pick the lines you like and that will be your repertoire.

Comment: The Kaufman Repertoire covers the Grunfeld as the d4 defense for Black.